# HTML drop down with large text selections aligns off page

Tags: php, html, css

I currently have a number of html drop-down lists that work ok apart from one with large text selections. Currently when selecting this particular drop down the list aligns off the web page to the left. I would ideally like the drop  down list to appear centered on the page. Is there a specific CSS styling that would allow this? Cheers

The below image shows an example of this. The entries further down the list are quite large hence why the list is so wide.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3svxw.png

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT `Contracted Support Hours` FROM poc_sla GROUP BY `Contracted Support Hours`"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);

?>

    <select  name="contracted_support_hours" id="contracted_support_hours" style="width:400px; text-align:center;" class="new_input_fields" required>

        <option value="">--Select--</option>

<?php

    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

?> 

        <option value="<?php echo $line['Contracted Support Hours'];?>"> <?php echo $line['Contracted Support Hours'];?> </option>

<?php
}
?>


    </select>
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML for the drop down?

Comment: The drop down is generated from php, not that it should make much difference

Comment: So is the dropdown going wide because of excessively wide content?

Comment: Unfortunately the dropdown is handled by the browsers chrome. Each browser will handle it slightly differently (some will go super wide, others might truncate at the middle or end). Your 2 reliable options are to programmatically crop the value to a specific max length, or override the select to display your own drop down that'll let you have more control over the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to cut the strings in PHP to a limit of characters.

In your while:

```
 <option value="<?php echo $line['Contracted Support Hours'];?>"> 
         <?php echo ((strlen($line['Contracted Support Hours']) > 150) ?
               substr($line['Contracted Support Hours'], 0, 150)."..." : 
               $line['Contracted Support Hours']);?> 
 </option>
```

**How does it works?**

Check if the string is more than 150 chars and if true, cut the string by 150 chars and add an ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

You can try css option selector then apply the style.

```
select, option { max-width: 100px; }
```

Or

```
select, option { width: [//Your custom]; }
```

Comment: Hi that just seems to resize the drop down select rather than options box it actually displays.